# NEAT - What is a good Compatability Threshold

Tags: neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I am learning about NEAT (Neuroevolution of Augmenting Topologies), and am trying to implement it in C++, and I have no idea of what a good compatability threshold would be, please can you recommend one, along with c1, c2 and c3 (see the distance function (δ) in the paper (page 13): http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/downloads/papers/stanley.ec02.pdf)

Comment: Is there any reason you are developing your own implementation? Because there are several ones. Check out the (NEAT Users Page)[https://www.cs.ucf.edu/~kstanley/neat.html]. If you still want to do it yourself, you can at least look there for some sensible defaults. But in the end, as with every evolutionary algorithm, some parameters might work sometimes but other times they won't.

Comment: I am making an implementation for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The compatibility threshold along with variables c1, c2 and c3, should all be chosen based on your problem, and other variables you've set for your NEAT implementation.  The larger your compatibility threshold is, the less species you'll have.  If your population size is small this will probably be what you want since you don't want your already small population to be divided much further.  However, if your population size is really big you can afford to have more species.  Another thing to note is that, in general, c1 and c2 should always be set to the same thing, since there isn't any difference in the way that disjoint and excess genes behave.  All you have to do now is determine how much you want the weights of each network to factor into speciation.  This, in my experience can only be adjusted through trial and error.